# Generator Transfer Switch for 2 Panels

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, generator, transfer-switch

I'd like to install a Transfer Switch (10 circuits) from the Generator to the two panels I have. Each panel is rated at 200 amps. If I turn off the main breaker in one of them, the other panel still works and vice versa. But I did find that the ground and neutral in both panels are all connected to each other.

So if I mount a transfer switch near them, would there be any issue if 6 circuits go to one panel and 4 circuits go to the second panel. Since the transfer switch only has one ground wire I believe and because the neutral and ground are connected in both panels, it wouldn't matter whichever panel I connect it to.

Any thoughts if this will be an issue?

**Update**

I can certainly try to go over the breakers that are critical and have an electrician move them over to one panel and then use a generator interlock switch on the top 2 right breakers, so either those 2 breakers can be on (powered by the generator) or the main breaker can be turned on. There are no spots for new breakers left, but the panel on left is smaller, so I can look into getting a bigger panel that'll allow more circuits

These transfer switches are definitely very expensive for only few circuits. But from theoretical standpoint, can you tell me why the transfer switch's 10 circuits can't be connected to two different panels, when the neutral/ground in both panels are connected to each other. (So the one neutral wire from the transfer switch can be connected to any panel)[image: Two Panels]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't swap the circuits around to get all the generator circuits on the same panel?

Comment: Why do you want to use one of those hokey "select circuit" switches to begin with? How big is your generator, and what circuits are you trying to move over to standby power?

Comment: And yes, can you post photos of your panels please?

Comment: Can you explain what the breaker labeled "Pump" is for?  Also, what does the 100A breaker in the top right of the left-hand panel feed?  And what breakers/circuits do you consider "critical"?

Answer (score 1):

### No, those things cannot serve 2 panels.

Technically, those 10-circuit transfer switches are a very bad choice generally.  Aside from being insanely overpriced for what they do, they also have severe limitations, including what you're running into here.

This issue comes up a lot. I realize the devices have a consumer appeal to you, but I strongly urge you to re-examine your options.

Let's start with a photo of your two main panels, or at least, the model numbers of them, so we can figure out what other options you have.  Are the panels right next to each other?  Also photos of the listing of circuits on both panels would be good.

Is there a reason you DON'T want to make generator power available to most of your circuits?  It seems a great inconvenience only being able to power 10.